# Query is not filtering data properly

Tags: oracle

I have a filteration for gridview which is on the basis of `project_id`, `date` and `vehicle_no`

but my query is not filtering properly.

Issue is:-

1. If I filter for today's date and check, the record does not show and data, which is perfectly correct.
2. But if filter for `exact date` , `project_id` and `vehicle_no` it should show one record. but it still doesn't shows any record.

Below is my query for filteration.

```
strquerry = "SELECT DISTINCT sv.mkey, vehicle_no, TO_CHAR (date_in, 'dd/MM/yyyy') || ' & ' || time_in vehicleindate_time, TO_CHAR (date_out, 'dd/MM/yyyy') || ' & ' " +
             "|| time_out vehicleoutdate_time, gate_no_in || ' & ' || gate_no_out ingate_outgateno, gd.good_type goods_type, net_weight netweight, TO_CHAR (challan_date, 'dd/MM/yyyy') " +
             "|| ' & ' || challan_no challandate_no,remark_in remarkin, NULL receipt_no, date_in FROM xxcus.xxgid_supinv sv, xxcus.xx_supinv_goodtype gd, " +
             "xxcus.xxacl_xxgid_user_mst ms WHERE (gd.good_type_code(+) = sv.good_type) AND " +
             "( sv.project_id = '" + cmbProjectName.SelectedValue + "' AND TO_CHAR (date_in, 'dd/MM/yyyy') = '" + txtExpCal.Value + "' OR vehicle_no = '" + ddlVehicleno.SelectedValue + "' ) ORDER BY date_in DESC, vehicle_no";
```

**UPDATE**

the real query after debugging

```
SELECT DISTINCT sv.mkey, vehicle_no,
               TO_CHAR (date_in, 'dd/MM/yyyy')
            || ' & '
            || time_in vehicleindate_time,
               TO_CHAR (date_out, 'dd/MM/yyyy')
            || ' & '
            || time_out vehicleoutdate_time,
            gate_no_in || ' & ' || gate_no_out ingate_outgateno,
            gd.good_type goods_type, net_weight netweight,
               TO_CHAR (challan_date, 'dd/MM/yyyy')
            || ' & '
            || challan_no challandate_no,
            remark_in remarkin, NULL receipt_no, date_in
       FROM xxcus.xxgid_supinv sv,
            xxcus.xx_supinv_goodtype gd,
            xxcus.xxacl_xxgid_user_mst ms
      WHERE (gd.good_type_code(+) = sv.good_type)
        AND (       sv.project_id = '1368'
                AND TO_CHAR (date_in, 'dd/MM/yyyy') = '19-09-2015'
             OR vehicle_no = '29'
            )
   ORDER BY date_in DESC, vehicle_no
```

Comment: Is it oracle or mysql? Edit the Question and leave correct tag (Looks like oracle is correct)

Comment: @StanislavL: my mistake, yes it's oracle. any help ??

Comment: What are real values of the controls? Debug and post real query string after filling the gaps. BTW it's SQL injection vulnerable. It's better to use parametrized queries rather than concatenation values.

Comment: @StanislavL: updated the question, parameterizes things i will take care of it

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `TO_CHAR (date_in, 'dd/MM/yyyy') = '19-09-2015'`

You convert date using `/` delimiter but the date from parameter has `-` delimiters.

Change it to `TO_CHAR (date_in, 'dd-MM-yyyy')`

Comment: but when I select from calendar the date comes in `21/01/2016` format, will that not be an issue ?

Comment: I know nothing about your calendar. Got the format just from your posted query

Comment: my calendar is `obout` calendar. `<input id="txtExpCal"  runat="server" maxlength="20" style="width: 70px;" type="text" />
                        <cc3:Calendar ID="CalEntryDt1" runat="server" DatePickerMode="true" TextBoxId="txtExpCal"
                            DatePickerImagePath="../Images/icon2.gif" CultureName="en-GB">
                        </cc3:Calendar>`

Comment: It's not SQL related:) I know nothing about the type of calendar. Try to google how the calendar sends data to your server (you may need to specify format or something like this). Or post a separate question here (with proper tags)

Comment: sure, will do that. thanks for this question's help :)

Comment: hi stanislavl, that problem still exist with my current code. Kindly suggest me the correct query